# Android ScanResult Timestamp Field - How accurate is it?

Tags: java, android, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I've been using wifiManager.startScan(); to receive the data from nearby Wi-Fi access points. This is returned as a List of ScanResult. This class can be found here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/ScanResult.html#timestamp

I understand that the Timestamp field of ScanResult is

> timestamp in microseconds (since boot) when this result was last
>   seen.

So I use some calculations to get the actual timestamp of when the access point was seen by the Smartphone device:

```
long actualTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis() - SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + (scanResult.timestamp / 1000);
```

This works fine, but I'm having some **rare** interesting results:

> 15:04:01 28-03-2016 - 1459173841
>
> 22:50:44 07-06-2016 - 1465336244
>
> 15:04:21 28-03-2016 - 1459173861

Notice above the entry for **June 2016**, a date in the future which is placed among the other readings gathered from within the List.

What could be happening here? Is my code slightly wrong? Is the timestamp value occasionally inaccurate? Has anyone experienced this before?

Edit: I am testing this on Nexus 5 Marshmallow device. MinSDK 18, Target 23

Comment: I'm getting some results that I don't trust either. I try to filter results that are older than X ms but I'm pretty sure that results in a list that contains scanresults that shouldn't be there or it contains an incorrect signal strength (my app tries to find the best access point and it consistently chooses AP's that *were* the best before I started moving towards another one) leading me to believe that the signal level and timestamp do not correspond.

Comment: Come to think of it.. maybe create an issue on the AOSP bug tracker about this?

Comment: @REJH since this post I was able to replicate the issue on one phone mainly through moving (walking, driving ect). The timestamp would end up being in the future. On a different device, a timestamp would remain in the results, never removed, meaning it would always be outdated. It's safe to presume that we can't trust all results - but we can filter them out. Record when you start the scan, and when it ends, then only select results from between that time frame.

Comment: My Samsung S6 and S7 also will return timestamp in future from once in a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have an explanation: this is a bug.

I see that occasionally .timestamp (microseconds since reboot) will be equal to .seen (seconds since Epoch). Nowadays Epoch time is approximately 17 days if reinterpreted as microseconds time period.

Since 2 values clearly cannot be equal, I submitted it to Android:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=225218
Feel free to star the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me

```
long actualTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos() - scanResult.getTimestampNanos(), TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
```